# "has been studied" versus "has studied"

Tags: difference, word-order

I know this sentence is correct:

> This problem has been studied by Dave

Is it also correct to say?

> This problem has studied by Dave

If not , why? From my previous knowledge, I guess we have to write "Dave has studied this problem". I might be wrong but that's why I'm confused.

If it is correct, what are the differences between the above sentence with this :

> This problem is studied by Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"This has studied by Dave."** is **not** correct but
**"Dave has studied this."** is correct.

I believe you have simply mixed up your conjugations after learning the passive voice.

"Has studied" is the Present **Active**  3rd person singular form of the verb "to study".  In your sentence, you are using an active verb in a passive sentence which is not allowed.

Comment: I almost knew that has studied by Dave is not correct, but I'm confused if  "has studied by Dave" is incorrect why is "has been studied by Dave" is correct? I assumed they are similar but "has been" continue a situation to the present. Am I wrong? Is "has been" passive?

Comment: Yes,  *has been studied* is a passive verb construction.

Comment: In English, sentences can either be expressed in the "Active voice" or the "Passive voice".  `In an Active sentence, the subject performs action on the object.`  For example:**Dave studies Math" is an active sentence because Dave (the subject) is performing the action (studies) on the object (Math).  `In a Passive sentence, the subject has an action performed on it by an agent (marked with "by").` For example:**Math is studied by Dave** is a passive sentence because Math (the subject) is having the action (is studied) performed on it by Dave (the agent). to be continued...

Comment: English verbs conjugate differently depending on whether the sentence is active or passive.  Passive constructions are characterized by a form of the verb "to be".  "Has been studied is the Present Perfect Passive form of to study. Has studied is the Present Perfect Active form of to study.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. Just for a double check. In the above example. The only difference between "This problem has been studied by Dave" and "This problem is studied by Dave" is the former one continues until the present?

Comment: Regarding your edited comment, I'm actually not sure why but "has studied" as well as "has been studied" definitely imply that the studying is **not** still continuing.  In most other verbs I can think of, the present perfect implies the action is continuing up to the mention of the verb but "to study" seems to be an exception.

Comment: Again, I'm not equipped to give a proper answer to why, but "is studied" implies that the action is continuing into the present (its active analog is "Dave studies this"). "has been studied" implies that is it not (its active analog is "Dave has studied this").

Comment: What if it's continuous? *HAS BEEN BEING STUDIED* ??

Comment: @Zakiya Honestly, I'm not certain "has been being studied" is grammatical (I'm also not certain that it is not grammatical). If it is in fact correct, it would mean that the studying began in the past and continues to the present moment (implying that it is still continuing). This meaning would much more likely be expressed using the active voice with a generic subject: "They've been studying it for years." or with a compound sentence: "It's been studied for years and continues (to be studied) to this  day."

Comment: Like, Cloning has been being studied since blah blah .. I have to look it up, I think .. Woop! Thanks for the response!